# How to iterate through two lists at once?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I had two lists,`foo` and `bar` instantiated as follows:

```
foo = ['Hello', 'Yes', 'No']
bar = ['Bonjour', 'Oui', 'Non']
```

Suppose, then, I wanted to iterate through the values and print a concatenation like so:

```
count = 0
for x in foo:
    print x + bar[count]
    count += 1
```

Which would give me:

> HelloBonjour
>
> YesOui
>
> NoNon

Would there be method that wouldn't require a count iterator? Perhaps something along the lines of...

```
for x in foo and y in bar:
    pint x + y
```

is available?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `zip`:

```
foo = ['Hello', 'Yes', 'No']
bar = ['Bonjour', 'Oui', 'Non']
for x, y in zip(foo, bar):
    print x + y
```

Output:

```
HelloBonjour
YesOui
NoNon
```

Comment: +1 for zip. If you're running an older version of python (< 3), it should be noted that `itertools.izip()` will do this lazily. Current versions of python seem to be lazy by default.

Comment: Specifically, Python 3.x is lazy. Python 2.7 is still current :)

Answer (score 0):

Zip is something that will help you when both your input lists are of equal size. If lists are of different size the operation will be performed only on the elements that have pair in the other list. If you want to fill the missing pairs with something you can use map:

```
for i,j in map(None,listA,listB):  
    print i+j
```

output:

```
HelloBonjour
YesOui
NoNon
```

Comment: ``itertools.izip_longest`` will do the job as well, perhaps with a clearer intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this guy:

```
print '\n'.join( map(lambda x, y: x+y, foo, bar) )
```